# How to add photos taken with the iOS SDK to the user's camera roll?

Tags: iphone, ios, ios5, camera, photo

My app allows users to take photos with the iOS SDK, and add them to data within the app. Is there a way to make it so that these photos are added to the camera roll, so that they can access them on their computers as well via Photo Stream?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

There is a function called `UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum` that will let you do this

```
UIImage* image = //image from somewhere
UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(image, nil, nil, nil);
```